# Understand shell script interpreter with custom shell

Tags: c++, linux, shell, interpreter

I try to understood how shell script interpreter working.
for example i wrote custom shell with c++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    string input;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "prompt:> ";
        cin >> input;
        if(input=="exit")
            return 0;
        else if(input=="test")
            cout << "You executed test command\n";
        else
            cout << "Unknown command.\n";
    }
}
```

now i wrote a script like this :

```
#!/PATH/TO/COMPILED/SHELL 
test
wrong_command1 
wrong_command2
exit
```

Actually this script not working and i want to understand what part of my thinking is wrong .
**Note:** I executed this script on `/bin/bash` shell .

1. can i say ,my c++ code is: `interactive shell`
2. How interpreters work on shell scripts ?  `#!/PATH/TO/COMPILED/SHELL`
3. How can fix code or script to activate interpreting feature ?

Comment: 'this script is not working' Can you **describe** in what way your code is not working? Because it is not obvious.

Comment: It's unclear whether you have problem with making the trick of the #! line work, or with running your program on a script. I would first debug your home-made scriptinterpretor by calling it explicitly (without relying on #!) and then get the #! stuff running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No idea what that means
2. If you compile your program to `/tmp/a.out` and have an executable file `script` with:

   ```
   #!/tmp/a.out
   test
   wrong_command1 
   wrong_command2
   exit
   ```

   which you invoke on command line as `./script` then the shell running the command line will invoke `/tmp/a.out ./script`. I.e. looks at the shebang, invokes that command and passes the script as its first argument. The rest is up to that command.
3. There is no interpreting feature in C++, you have to write it yourself, what you have is a good start except you need to read from the passed file argument, not stdin. Also `std::getline` might come handy.

Comment: do you mean , script executed line by line so i need to read script and execute commands line by line ? that is true ?

Comment: @mah454 That is entirely up to you but yes, that would be a good way to do this if you want to e.g. interpret bash.